# Cannot destroy THTTPReqResp component in a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, soap, delphi-xe

I am having problems using SOAP in XE/XE2 from a thread. (I didn't test it with older Delphis.) A simple code that works in the main thread crashes while destroying the THTTPReqResp instance with `Invalid pointer operation`.

This is the complete program. The form contains only one button which triggers btnTestClick event:

```
unit Unit79;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Forms, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, ComObj,
  ActiveX, InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPTrans, Rio, SOAPHTTPClient;

type
  TForm79 = class(TForm)
    btnTest: TButton;
    procedure btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form79: TForm79;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm79.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      FHTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;
      FHTTPRIO: THTTPRIO;
    begin
      if CoInitializeEx(NIL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED or COINIT_SPEED_OVER_MEMORY) = S_OK then try
        FHTTPReqResp := THTTPReqResp.Create(nil);
        with FHTTPReqResp do begin
          Name := 'HTTPReqResp1';
          UseUTF8InHeader := True;
          InvokeOptions := [soIgnoreInvalidCerts, soAutoCheckAccessPointViaUDDI];
          WebNodeOptions := [];
        end;
        FHTTPRIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
        with FHTTPRIO do begin
          Name := 'HTTPRIO1';
          HTTPWebNode := FHTTPReqResp;
        end;
        //
        FreeAndNil(FHTTPRIO);
        FreeAndNil(FHTTPReqResp); //<-- crashes here
      finally CoUninitialize; end;
    end
  ).Start;
end;

end.
```

The exception is raised in TObject.FreeInstance on the _FreeMem call.

```
procedure TObject.FreeInstance;
begin
  CleanupInstance;
  _FreeMem(Self);
end;
```

The call stack leading to this problem is

> ```
> :75bab9bc KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x58 System.TObject.FreeInstance
> System.ErrorAt(2,$4052E1) System.Error(reInvalidPtr)
> System.TObject.FreeInstance System._ClassDestroy(???)
> Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans.THTTPReqResp.Destroy System.TObject.Free
> frmMain.TMainForm.btnTestClick$4934$ActRec.$0$Body
> System.Classes.TAnonymousThread.Execute
> System.Classes.ThreadProc($F83530) System.ThreadWrapper($F51050)
> :76a4339a kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 :77b59ef2
> ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 :77b59ec5
> ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36
> ```

I have absolutely no idea what's going on, why _ClassDestroy is called at all and why the code crashes :( Can somebody please a) explain what I'm doing wrong and b) fix my code?

Comment: D2010 doesn't have CreateAnonymousThread yet. Trying with non-anonymous now. No crashes with non-anonymous thread.

Comment: Threading is not an issue here (I think). It crashes the same with OmniThreadLibrary (which was how I found this problem).

Comment: From the documentation of THttprio "When it is created with a nil (Delphi) or NULL (C++) parameter, it will auto-destroy when the references count drops to zero". You are explicitly freeing it.

Comment: Try freeing FHTTPReqResp before freeing FHTTPRIO. this is just a haunch though because `HTTPWebNode := FHTTPReqResp`...

Comment: strike that, I didn't read LU RD comment before posting (I believe he got the right answer).

Comment: And you can set the owner property of FHttpReqResp to FHTTPRIO and forget about both FreeAndNil statements.

Comment: @LU RD - I don't understand - make this an answer with a code sample, please.

Comment: I think Rob has it well covered. What I was trying to say was as he so well explains it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Invalid pointer operation" means you're freeing something that doesn't represent valid memory. That can sometimes indicate stack or heap corruption, but it more likely indicates that you're freeing something that has already been freed.

It's no surprise that `_ClassDestroy` is called. `FHTTPReqResp` is non-null, so when `FreeAndNil` calls `Free` on it, `Free` calls `Destroy`.

It would appear that your `THTTPRIO` object acquires ownership of the `THTTPReqResp` you give it. If that's the case, then the solution is simple: don't free it yourself.

Comment: You're correct. Freeing just FHTTPRIO destroys both as FastMM4 FullDebugMode confirm. Stupid code architecture, I would never think of that!

Comment: The SOAP architecture is nothing but chock full of "Yuck!" moments.  I spent a year working with it.  My least favorite aspect of it is the way it normally depends on WinInet, which is buggy and has timeout/freeze-ups on some Windows systems.  When you switch to indy-based HTTPRIO transport you lose the random freezes, but you get an overall drop in performance of about 40%.  Nice choice.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I am having a memory leak problem and hopefully this solves it.